# Is this a Phishing email a bit more advanced than usual?

Tags: email, phishing

I received an email from a friend, but it was not them. It was their name in the sender field but there was a different email address hidden underneath. There was a zip file attachment.

But here’s the bit that I’m worried about: the body text of the email was an email conversation from a year ago that took place with that friend. I’m worried that my sent emails have been accessed somehow and will be sent out to the world.

Comment: Not that unusual and this is going on for a while: [Emotet Malware Revives Old Email Conversations Threads to Increase Infection Rates](https://www.spamtitan.com/blog/emotet-malware-revives-old-email-conversations-threads-to-increase-infection-rates/), [Emotet hijacks email conversation threads to insert links to malware](https://www.zdnet.com/article/emotet-hijacks-email-conversation-threads-to-insert-links-to-malware/).

Comment: You have no control over the emails you have sent to others. They are already "out in the world"

Comment: Thank you Steffen I’ll look in to that. And yes Schroeder I guess they are! I have another question now in that could my email history be sent out to someone in my contacts through this kind of virus? I’m worried as I have a lot of confidential health correspondence and wouldn’t want it mailed to my contacts address book. Should I delete the account maybe?

Comment: **"... I have a lot of confidential ... "** and **email** do not mix! Unless you encrypt your email, do not trust confidential information to it. In the case of *health correspondence* it may even be a violation of HIPAA.

Comment: Ok thank you, I had no idea, I’ll look in to encrypting and how to do that thank you